# trouble filling bidimensional Array with objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got this array in a "global" position (out of every function in my doc).

```
var arrayBidimensional;
```

Then, i'm trying to filling it like this:

```
var objetoLetra = new objectLetter("","","","","");    

arrayBidimensional=new Array(tamano);

for (i=0; i <tamano; i++)
arrayBidimensional[i]=new Array(tamano);

var random = Math.floor((Math.random()*26)+0); 

for (var i = tamano - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
{
    for (var j = tamano - 1; j >= 0; j--) 
    {
        random = Math.floor((Math.random()*26)+0);
        objetoLetra.letra = letras[random];
        objetoLetra.letraposx = j;
        objetoLetra.letraposy = i;
        objetoLetra.formapalabra = "no";
        objetoLetra.iden = j+""+i;
        arrayBidimensional[i][j] = objetoLetra;            
    }

}
```

so when i tried to reach to this array in some position like `array[X][X]`

all i've got is the very first position. Example: if the first position (That is 0,0) is "A", then, the entire array got "A" on every single position, even if it is [(max position), (max position)].

How do i see that?, well, i'm building a Table with td-s like this:

```
'<td width="30">'+arrayBidimensional[i][j].letra+'</td>'
```

Then, the entire table is just a lot of "A" every single cell... So... What i am doing wrong?

Please and thank you!

Comment: You're either missing code, or lack an understanding of JavaScript altogether.

Comment: Can you paste your code for defining objectLetter? Also, where do you get "tamano"?

Comment: `arrayBidimensional=new Array(tamano);` would be an Array with one element that is an Array itself. What would the point of that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new `objectLetter` for each location in the array:

```
arrayBidimensional = new Array(tamano);

for (i=0; i < tamano; i++) {
    arrayBidimensional[i] = new Array(tamano);
}

for (var i = tamano - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
{
    for (var j = tamano - 1; j >= 0; j--) 
    {
        var objetoLetra = new objectLetter("","","","","");    
        var random = Math.floor((Math.random()*26)+0);

        objetoLetra.letra = letras[random];
        objetoLetra.letraposx = j;
        objetoLetra.letraposy = i;
        objetoLetra.formapalabra = "no";
        objetoLetra.iden = j+""+i;
        arrayBidimensional[i][j] = objetoLetra;            
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is exacly what i needed, i was creating just one object for the entire array, but "re-creating" the object for each position was the perfect solution, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what a Multidimensional Array should look like in JavaScript:

```
var multi = [['String', 0, 'something else'],['another String', 42, 'whatever']];
```

or

```
var multi = new Array(new Array('String', 0, 'something else'), new Array('another String', 42, 'whatever'));

console.log(multi[1][2]); // 'whatever'
console.log(multi[0][1]); // 0
```